# insert into parent and child table using oracle forall

Tags: oracle, parent-child, bulkinsert

I have a requirement where i need to insert data into a parent and child table in oracle 11g

Insert data into the parent table and for all the success records insert the data into the child table.

I want to use the bulk processing to achieve this.

I was able to insert the records into the parent table and use the return clause to get the PK into collection

but i am struck how to insert into the child table using the returned collection

Please could you help me with the example how to achieve it.

p.S : i am not having the create type access

Thanks

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far

Comment: yes you need to post code or approach you are trying. also post data structure of table.

Comment: `OPEN ID_TYPE FOR 'select ID 
,NAME
,CITY FROM PARENT_TABLE ' ;

 LOOP
    BEGIN
      FETCH ID_TYPE BULK COLLECT INTO CURSOR_FETCH LIMIT 1000;      EXIT
    WHEN CURSOR_FETCH.COUNT = 0;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('eqpmt id count :' || CURSOR_FETCH.COUNT);
     FORALL I IN 1..CURSOR_FETCH.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS

INSERT INTO MAIN_PARENT (ID 
,NAME
,CITY)
                                         VALUES (CURSOR_FETCH(I).ID,
        CURSOR_FETCH(I).NAME,
        CURSOR_FETCH(I).CITY) RETURNING CURSOR_FETCH(I).ID BULK COLLECT INTO L_ID;

END;
COMMIT;
END LOOP;`

Comment: i have added the code for the parent table insert,i now need the insert for the child table using the l_ID collection

Comment: Please add code by editing the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR cOld IS
      SELECT *
      FROM my_list;

   new_id  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   FOR rOld IN cOld LOOP
      new_id := sup_seq.NEXTVAL;  -- Get the ID to use for the new row

      INSERT INTO my_list
             (sup_id,sup_name,sup_code)
      VALUES (new_id,rOld.sup_name,rOld.sup_code);

      INSERT INTO my_list_details
            (buy_id,sup_id,sup_detail,max_amount,min_amount)
      SELECT buy_seq.NEXTVAL,new_id,sup_detail,max_amount,min_amount
      FROM   my_list_details
      WHERE  sup_id = rOld.sup_id;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: thanks.i want to use the bulk processing to achieve this